# How to handle multiple keyboards compose key?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have a laptop keyboard with right AltGr, PrintSc and Right CTRL and a MacOS X one with right Super and right Alt.

When using one, I'd like the right ctrl to be the compose key and when using the other one, I'd like the right alt to be the compose key.

Do you know if it is possible to use the XKB options to configure that?

I tried `['ctrl:rctrl_ralt', 'compose:ralt']` but no luck so far.

Comment: To be honest I would really like to be able to set those options with regards to the selected keyboard layout,

Comment: A current hack is to set `['altwin:swap_lalt_lwin', 'lv3:rwin_switch', 'compose:ralt']` but it just allows me to configure the mac keyboard as expected

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a couple of aliases to this commands:

**Laptop Keyboard**

```
alias xkb-linux-on="gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options \"['compose:rctrl']\""
```

**MacOS Keyboard**

```
 alias xkb-macos-on="gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options \"['altwin:swap_lalt_lwin', 'lv3:rwin_switch', 'compose:ralt']\""
```

If anybody knows how to run them when switching input-sources, I would be interested.